# I cannot figure out the differences between setting the Submission policy (Open, Close) for the Metadata navigation service

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, administration, managed-metadata-service

I have created a metadata managed service, and for one the the term sets I define the Submission policy to be Open, instead of Close, as follow:-
[image]

But nothing have changes, I thought that specifying the term set to be open will allow users to add terms to the term set, without the need to login to the central administration as I am currently doing.

So basically I have these two questions:-

- What are the differences between specifying the Submission policy to be Open or to be Close.
- Is there a way to allow users or group of users to be able to add terms to a term set, without the need to login to the central administration site?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically selection of submission policy (Open or close) will define whether a user can add new terms in the term store or term store managed by the Managers.

- Anyone can add a new term to an open term set.
- For Closed Term set only administrator can add it. Only people who
  were identified as contributors to a term set group can add terms to
  a closed term set in the group

**Their are 2 types of term set scope, Global & local.**

- Local: If you are adding a term to a local term set, you must start
  this procedure from the site collection to which the term set
  belongs.
- Global: If you are updating a global term set, you can open the Term
  Store Management Tool from any site.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/create-and-manage-terms-in-a-term-set-HA102771989.aspx